# Unable to addExtra in IntentIntegrator

Tags: android, zxing

I am trying to attach some custom data before starting of scanning and want this data to be available onActivityResult. To do this i have added some string like this:

```
IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(Arrays.asList("QR_CODE", "CODE_128"));
integrator.addExtra(SCAN_LOCAL, "Local_str");
integrator.initiateScan();
```

and after successful scanning, when I try to get

```
String local= intent.getStringExtra(SCAN_LOCAL);
```

Nothing available for in extra except the scanning results. Is it a bug? any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're simply not using it right.
You added some extra, `SCAN_LOCAL`, which the receiving Activity doesn't know how to handle. You are expecting them to echo back all the extra's? I don't think it's doing it.

Anyhow, if you just wanna use `"Local_str"` when the QR activity is done, why not just save it as a member just before sending the Intent, and use it when `onActivityResult`?

Comment: Well, actually it is using to handle different scenarios that I am doing after getting scan results and it is dynamic value..

Comment: @user565 is this value being produced in the QR Activity?